# Is a sledge hammer a reasonable weapon choice for an entire story?

Tags: warfare, weapons

I'm writing this video game and I decided to focus on a single weapon type for the combat. As the title implies, the main/playable character exclusively uses two-handed hammers as weapons. While this decision came as a result of the combat I'm planning, I do think I need to justify the main character's choice within the game's narrative.

To that end, this character used to be part of a peasants rebellion (the setting is a European-ish feudal society in the medieval ages). During this time, he leaned how to use his above average strength and a sledge hammer to bust through the plate and chainmail armor of aristocratic knights. Due to having a lot of experience with this style of fighting and no training with other weapons, he will forgo using swords, axes, or ranged weapons in order to stick with what he knows even when fighting unarmored or bestial opponents.

So, my question is, **is the above reasons sufficient justification for my character's fixation on sledge hammers, and, if not, what else could be done?**

Some information of dubious relevance is that the character is much stronger than his size implies (he is slightly below the average height at the time), he is in hiding after leaving the rebellion (his side lost), and he does have *narrative* opportunities to acquire more traditional armaments. I can't just say the all shops only stock sledge hammers after all, so I need the character to actively not care to try other types of weapons.

[image]

This is an image showing the relative size of the hammers in question.

Comment: I love the idea, but the question is off-topic as too story-based.  Whether or not any weapon is appropriate in this circumstance is entirely up to you and the backstory you write to justify it.  In other words, your question isn't about a rule of your world, it's about an aesthetic.  Personally, if I thought the guy approaching me had the wherewithal to swing a sledge with authority, I'd poop my pants and run.  So, short answer, sure.  Love the idea.

Comment: You know what they say: when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: The WB stack is more about problems encountered while building worlds and how to solve them / achieve a goal. Questions about characters / stories are off-topic as defined in the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question should be on-topic though on either the [gamedev stack](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) and/or the [writers stack](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: NB4 Peter Gabriel shows up... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJWJE0x7T4Q

Comment: There's another advantage for him choosing the mallet as a weapon. It was an extremely usual tool for woodcutters, so nobody will suspect of him. And blacksmiths can repair it because they are used to it.

Comment: Yes, theres reasons to be using almost exclusively a hammer. Before firearms plate armor was a very powerful tool of protection. During this time, blunt force weapons started to become more common. The pommel on swords was even introduced for exactly this purpose: you grab the sword in reverse and use the pommel as a club against an armored opponent. Flails and the like became popular then as well. So if plate armor is pretty common (and considering a peasant with a hammer on the losing side is wearing some it seems common) using a hammer is MORE sensible theb using swords or ranged weapons.

Comment: "Hey, put hammer-guy out front to clear the pikes out the way...oh, he got shot in the face/leg/arm with an arrow."

Comment: @dot_Sp0T For what I understand of their posted rules, I am unsure if either of the stacks you recommended would host this question. Both seem more focused on the technical aspects rather than the content of their respected mediums. As far as I can tell, the best thing for me to do is ask some people IRL and go with my gut.

Comment: Sad it's off-topic as this is a neat idea :) perhaps we need a 'characters and concepts' stack exchange. As for my 2c, perhaps the hammer has become a status symbol of the rebels. Perhaps a defining moment of the revolt was your chap caving in the head of a particularly brutal and disliked knight. Combine this with the fact that hammers are quite common tools for peasants so it's hard to pull off a 'kill anyone who has a hammer' order and everything starts coming together :)

Comment: (1/2) That's not enough reason. You are way better off with axes or picks as anti-armour weapons. In fact, war hammers usually featured large spike specifically to give them armour piercing capability. Yes, you can do blunt damage trauma through armour, but you are better off concentrating the blow on small area to pierce armour, hence a spike. And thrusting sword techniques. And thrusting weapons. Make him a woodcutter or miner and make him pick up a Horseman's Pick after some dead knight. He will feel at home with that weapon, and it can realistically be useful in any situation...

Comment: (2/2) ... just be aware that he will be relatively slow. Unless he acquires armour and shield of his own, a competent swordsman will have little trouble killing your protagonist. Sword thrusts are VERY fast and much less telegraphed than swing with a hammer. Without shield to parry or armour capable of stopping slow thrusts he's an easy target as he makes a swing.

Comment: Maybe he only uses a hammer because he's stuck in a Cauldron and needs the hammer to move around? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Over_It_with_Bennett_Foddy

Answer (score 3):

**His experience with the hammer should be prior to his experience as a warrior.**

[image: maul for driving posts]
https://smallfarmersjournal.com/driving-fence-posts-by-hand/

Yes he was in a peasants rebellion and yes he used his big hammer to effect.  But the reason he had that hammer was that before the rebellion, he earned a living with it driving things into the ground.  He was assigned hammer work as a very large and slow-witted teenager, and was so good at it that he never did anything else.  He considers his current job to be a sort of extension of his old one.

I picture this dude less like kung fu Boba Fett in your image and more like Lenny from  Of Mice and Men.  Lenny has a limited number of hammer moves.  He has not needed more.